# How to make a form invisible when the page loads in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

How to make a form invisible when the page loads in asp.net C#? At button(Show) it should be visible. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear but you can use the default page load function

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        yourForm.visible = false;
 }

 private void your_btn_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       yourForm.visible = true;
 }
```